# prove that if $a_1 a_2\cdots a_n=1$ implies $a_1^{n-1}+a_2^{n-1}+\cdots a_n^{n-1}\geq \frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots+ \frac{1}{a_n}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let us consider $a_1,a_2,\cdots a_n>0$ such that  $a_1 a_2\cdots a_n=1$ then show that  $a_1^{n-1}+a_2^{n-1}+\cdots a_n^{n-1}\geq \frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\cdots \frac{1}{a_n}$.

*Attempt 1(definition)*

Since the the inequality is equal to $(\frac{a_1^n}{a_1}-\frac{1}{a_1})+(\frac{a_2^n}{a_2}-\frac{1}{a_2})+\cdots +(\frac{a_n^n}{a_n}-\frac{1}{a_n})\geq 0$
but the inequality $$\frac{1}{a_1}(a_1^n-1)\geq 0$$ can´t be true for each $a_i$.

*Attempt 2 (by substitution)*

Now from our hypothesis
$\frac{1}{a_i}=a_1a_2\cdots \hat{a_i} a_{i+1}\cdots a_n$ and putting it in our inequality
$a_1^n(a_2a_3\cdots a_n)+a_2^n(a_1a_3\cdots a_n)+\cdots + a_n^n(a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1})\geq (a_2a_3\cdots a_n)+(a_1a_3\cdots a_n)+\cdots +(a_1a_2\cdots a_{n-1})$

but each $a_i>0$ and hence $\frac{1}{a_i}>0$ and then our assertion is true.

*Attempt 3 (rearrangement inequality)*

WLOG assume that $a_1\leq a_2\cdots \leq a_n$ I need find a collection of ordered numbers  $b_1\leq b_2\cdots b_n$
for use that $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\cdots a_nb_n\geq a_1b_{\sigma(1)}+a_2b_{\sigma(2)}+\cdots+a_nb_{\sigma(n)}$
where $\sigma\in S_n$.

But I cant figure out how should be $b_i$ for each $i$.

Any advice or hint was helpful.

Comment: One liner without thinking. Bunching with exponents ( n-1,0,..0 ) and (1,...,1,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
a_1^{n-1}+a_2^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{n-1}^{n-1}\ge (n-1)\sqrt[n-1]{a_1^{n-1}a_2^{n-1}\ldots a_{n-1}^{n-1}}=(n-1)a_1a_2\ldots a_{n-1}=\frac{n-1}{a_n}.
$$

Can you continue now?